# stemCompletion is not working properly

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, stemming

I am trying to use stemCompletion to convert the stemmed words into complete words.

Following is the code I am using

```
txt <- c("Once we have a corpus we typically want to modify the documents in it",
     "e.g., stemming, stopword removal, et cetera.",
     "In tm, all this functionality is subsumed into the concept of a transformation.")

myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus

# *Removing common word endings* (e.g., "ing", "es") 
myCorpus.stemmed <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
myCorpus.unstemmed <- tm_map(myCorpus.stemmed, stemCompletion, dictionary=myCorpusCopy)
```

if I check the first element for stemmed corpus, it shows me the element correctly

```
myCorpus.stemmed[[1]][1]
$content
[1] "onc we have a corpus we typic want to modifi the document in it"
```

But if I check the first element of unstemmed corpus, it throws out junk

```
myCorpus.unstemmed[[1]][1]
$content
[1] NA
```

Why is the unstemmed corpus not showing the right content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the unstemmed corpus not showing the right content?

Since you got a simple corpus object, you are effectively calling

```
stemCompletion(
  x = c("once we have a corpus we typically want to modify the documents in it", 
        "eg stemming stopword removal et cetera", 
        "in tm all this functionality is subsumed into the concept of a transformation"),
  dictionary=myCorpusCopy
)
```

which yields

```
# once we have a corpus we typically want to modify the documents in it 
# NA 
# eg stemming stopword removal et cetera 
# NA 
# in tm all this functionality is subsumed into the concept of a transformation 
# NA
```

due to `stemCompletion` awaiting a character vector of stems as a first argument (`c("once", "we", "have")`), not a character vector of stemmed texts (`c("once we have")`).

If you want to complete the stems in your corpus, whatever this is supposed to be good for, you have to pass a character vector of single stems to `stemCompletion` (i.e. tokenize each text document, stem-complete the stems, then paste them together again).

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. It guided me in the right direction and I was able to find a custom function which helped me convert the text into a character vector of stems before applying the stemCompletion function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only slightly familiar with TM, but doesn't stemCompletion require that the tokens be stems and not already completed words.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I forgot to change the corpus name when typing my code here. I have made the correction. The error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer given by [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022937/4437750), I looked for a function which can help convert the example text to character vector.

I came across another question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391686/4437750) which gives a custom function which can convert text to individual words before applying stemCompletion function.

```
stemCompletion_mod <- function(x,dict=dictCorpus) {
 PlainTextDocument(stripWhitespace(paste(stemCompletion(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x)," ")),dictionary=dict, type="shortest"),sep="", collapse=" ")))
}
```

I combined the function with lapply to get a list containing unstemmed version. This returns the right values but its not in the SimpleCorpus data type! I needed to do some jugglery with the output list to convert it into SimpleCorpus data type.

```
myCorpus.unstemmed <- lapply(myCorpus.stemmed, stemCompletion_mod, dict = myCorpusCopy)

> myCorpus.stemmed[[1]][1]
$content
[1] "onc we have a corpus we typic want to modifi the document in it"

 > myCorpus.unstemmed[[1]][1]
$content
[1] "once we have a corpus we typically want to the documents in it"
```

I don't know why stemCompletion didn't complete modifi. But that will be part of another question to explore.